# Using Arduino IDE to build Ardupilot code

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I try to open and compile arduPilot code using Arduino IDE (V. 1.0.5). But it's not working. I found the code is not compatible with standard IDE.

How can you modify the code and build it? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It just worked for me. ArduPilot 2.7.1 and Arduino 1.0.5 on Windows.

Note that the ArduPilot build was last updated in 2010, back when Arduino was not using the new INO files, but PDE files. So you have to manually go to file->open, then select ardupilot_2-7.pde to open.

Comment: Seeing your reply I've tried with ardupilot 2.7.1 (found [in here](https://code.google.com/p/ardupilot/downloads/list)), and yes, it's working. But as i have a ardupilot mega module, i've tried with ArduPlane 2.74b ([here](https://code.google.com/p/ardupilot-mega/downloads/list)), but it's not working. I'm new to this. Would you please explain the difference between two codes?

Comment: Ah, ArduPilot is the "original" code designed for multirotor craft. For some reason to compile ArduPlane, you have to use their modified IDE which can be downloaded here: https://code.google.com/p/ardupilot-mega/downloads/detail?name=ArduPilot-Arduino-1.0.3-windows.zip&can=2&q

Answer (score 1):

As you can see above ArduPilot has a modified Arduino IDE. The [Visual Micro plugin for Atmel Studio](http://www.visualmicro.com/post/2013/05/02/APM-Installation-Guide.aspx) also supports the APM modifications.